# How To Disable Multiple input Tags With One Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html

When I choose the option that activates the JavaScript only one of the inputs works. How can I make the both of them to work using that JavaScript code?

```js
var myselect = document.getElementById('myselect');

function createOption() {
  var currentText = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
  var objOption = document.createElement("option");
  objOption.text = currentText;
  objOption.value = currentText;
}

myselect.onchange = function() {
  var mytextfield = document.getElementById('mytext');
  if (myselect.value !== 'specify') {
    mytextfield.disabled = true;
  } else {
    mytextfield.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class='form-control' id='myselect' required style='cursor:pointer;'>
<option disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
<option>Here</option>
<option value='specify'>Outside Here - Specify Below</option>
</select>

<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='email'>Specify:</label>
  <input class='form-control' type='text' value='' name='mytext' id='mytext' disabled placeholder='Specify Here' required>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='email'>Specify:</label>
  <input class='form-control' type='text' value='' name='mytext' id='mytext' disabled placeholder='Specify Here' required>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't select multiple elements at once with `getElementById`. You should use `querySelectAll` or select all records with `getElementById` one by one. However, I don't recommend writing javascript in the html `onclick` attribute. Is there any reason why you're not making a script?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName` is what you want/need

Comment: Elements on a page cannot have duplicate `id` values. All `id` values must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myfunction()
{
var e = document.getElementById("letter_number");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if(strUser == "Letters")
{
 document.getElementById("letter1" ).disabled=false;
 document.getElementById("letter2" ).disabled=false;
 document.getElementById("letter3" ).disabled=false;
 document.getElementById("number1" ).disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("number2" ).disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("number3" ).disabled=true;
 }
else
{
 

 document.getElementById("letter1" ).disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("letter2" ).disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("letter3" ).disabled=true;
 document.getElementById("number1" ).disabled=false;
 document.getElementById("number2" ).disabled=false;
 document.getElementById("number3" ).disabled=false;
}
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myfunction()" id="letter_number">
<option name="type" value="Letters">Letters</option>
<option selected name="type" value="Numbers">Numbers</option>
</select>
<select id="letter1" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Letters</option>
       <option>Letters</option>
</select>
<select id="letter2" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Letters</option>
       <option>Letters</option>
</select>
<select id="letter3" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Letters</option>
       <option>Letters</option>
</select><br><br>

<select id="number1" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Numbers</option>
       <option>Numbers</option>
</select>
<select id="number2" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Numbers</option>
       <option>Numbers</option>
</select>
<select id="number3" disabled="disabled">
       <option>Numbers</option>
       <option>Numbers</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like you are using the same id of the input field twice and that's the bug behind your code. 
**One Way to Fix this** is to change and declare another id for the second id, select with javascript then make your code whatever you want to with the new `var`.

**Or**

You can set a same class to the input fields then with javascript select the class with: 
`var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASS_NAME");`

This will return an array... but you can select a input field by :
`var firstField = inputs[0], secondField = inputs[1]`
This is not the recommended method but works like a charm.